# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib

Tags: xcode, swift

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib. Issue persist

I know that theses question have been answered several times, but **"dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib"** I have not been able to find a proper solution to this error when I am coding a Swift 
application for XCode 7.2:

Here I use Contact & ContactUI Frameworks:: **@rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C0F2B5CB-628C-4643-9473-648D3099D8FB/HomeMadeFood_User.app/HomeMadeFood_User
 Reason: image not found
```

I have tried all these actions:

- Restarting Xcode, iPhone, computer
- Cleaning & rebuilding
- Revoking and creating new certificate/provision profile
- Runpath Search Paths is '$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks'
- Embedded Content Contains Swift Code is 'Yes'
- Code Signing Identity is developer
- deleting Xcode's Derived Data directory.

  but I have always got the same error...
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

I tried like this: but i am getting an error like:

```
/Users/mac-jarc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HomeMadeFood_User-bmwdevsopruaqxfrbibhaspidobn/Build/Products/Debug-    iphoneos/HomeMadeFood_User.app/Frameworks/Contacts.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I had this same error for a couple of weeks:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib
```

Basically I was able to run and test my app on device. Then about 2 weeks ago, I wasn't able to run the tests on device anymore. Tests were running fine on simulator. I can't think what changed. The error I saw was the one above. I searched Google for ages trying to find a solution, and tried many fixes unsuccessfully. The fix that finally worked was to delete the Derived Data. Once I did this, I was once again able to run the tests on my device.

Fix that worked for me:

1. Go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data (click on little arrow to open up the folder in finder)
   e.g. `/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
2. Delete the entire DerivedData folder
3. Clean/Build
4. Test on device - finally works again

Answer (score 2):

In our case, it was clear that there was a bug in the way Xcode was resolving dependencies to our target.

Let's me start by saying, the solution was:

```
import PassKit
```

Now, before you raise that eyebrow, here is why this worked:

1. We relied on a Swift framework that imports `PassKit`
2. We distributed the prebuilt binary to team members
3. The team observed the crash, just as OP mentioned it
4. Adding that import in the app target made Xcode embed the required swift libraries

*Note: Just linking PassKit in the GUI did absolutely nothing.*

Answer (score 2):

Cracked it.

Check if the framework you're trying to build or one of it's dependency framework uses any of the Swift standard libraries. If yes, create a NEW key in the build settings

ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES;

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to invalid certification of Apple.

Go to your keychain access. Under "Keychains" select "System" and under "Category" select "Certificates". Check whether the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" is valid or not. If not download that certificate from Apple site. It'll solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure?  I have a valid macOS certificate (I just checked) and I get the same linker error that was described.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but this is [what helped me](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robovm/3E3xZ3r-J7c/sH2f8JjVAgAJ)
Speaking shortly:

```
EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES
```