# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib, Swift 2.2 crash continues

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

This question have been asked a lot of times, yet i am asking it again. Because none of the solutions worked for me.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A5F11EB9-3A99-4A28-A074-B9E17819C3A1/Notes.app/Notes
  Reason: image not found
```

I am on Xcode 7.3 and using Swift 2.2.

I have tried almost all of the approach from the following posts:

- [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)
- [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib)
- [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib / Image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104975/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib-image-not-found)
- [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986456/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcontacts-dylib)

But none of those seems to work for me. I am totally going crazy. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you doing any code-signing outside of the Xcode build process?  If you are then you are likely not re-signing the dylibs before re-signing the .ipa file.  I had that problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib where I managed to find a fix.