# How does the usage of print() anywhere in the code will somehow force libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to be loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild

Problem is, I got this well known IOS error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib Referenced from: /Users/<MY_USER>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AEAA313-0C65-49D8-BC20-DCC9994719C4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/48DC52C0-4BC6-45ED-9AEE-A0E1F5C8BA1B/P2P-1-<MY_APP>.app/Frameworks/<REQUIRED_FRAMEWORK>.framework/<REQUIRED_FRAMEWORK>
```

And after I tried every given logical solution like the ones suggested in these threads:

[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986082/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftswiftononesupport-dylib)

[Xcode - Bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)

[References to Removed Framework in project.pbxproj File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287250/references-to-removed-framework-in-project-pbxproj-file)

The only solution what was working was using swift's print() anywhere in the code, because this will somehow force libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to be loaded. What is the connection between these two? And what is the right way to load this missing library?

Details about the project:

- Cordova based mobile app
- Native IOS written in Objective-C
- Swift is only used after one of the libraries required it somehow

To be a bit more specific with this last point, our project relys on a not mainstream framework which uses swift. And we had this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib
```

Solution comes from here: [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986456/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcontacts-dylib)

We had to create a swift file in our project and have to import the required frameworks in that swift file.